# File name for file on Arduino SD card won't save

Tags: arduino

I'm making a data logging system, just for fun and learning the language. If I want to save a variable ".txt" file with an INT it works fine. Now I bought an RTC and I want the name to be as following: "Data_'DATE&TIME'.txt".

As you can see in the code below, I made a function newFileName what should be doing this, but my output also below is nothing like it. And on the SD card nothing even saves.

The things in comments are things I tried.

```
int CURRENT_FILE        = 1;
String dataString       = "";
String currentFileName  = "";
String currentTimeStamp = "";

void setDatumTijd(){
  t = rtc.getTime();
  currentTimeStamp = rtc.getDateStr();
  currentTimeStamp += "--"; 
  currentTimeStamp += rtc.getTimeStr();
  currentTimeStamp.replace(':', '.');
  delay(50);
}

void makeNewFile(String currentTimeStamp){
  char fileName[50];
  char timeStamp[20];
 // sprintf(timeStamp, currentTimeStamp.c_str());
  sprintf(fileName, "Data_%d.txt", currentTimeStamp.c_str());
  //currentFileName = fileName;
  //currentFileName.toCharArray(fileName,50);
  //currentTimeStamp += ".txt";
  //currentTimeStamp.toCharArray(fileName, (currentTimeStamp.length()+1));
  Serial.println(fileName);
  currentFileName = fileName;
  File dataFile = SD.open(fileName, FILE_WRITE);
  saveHeader(currentFileName, currentTimeStamp);
  dataFile.close();
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZHUi.png)

Answer (score 1):

The library that comes with Arduino doesn't support long filenames, it only supports "8 bytes for filename"."3 bytes for file type", and in your case, it is clearly exceeding that limit.
This all is due to the reason that most of the Arduino boards has lesser RAM.
But if you still want to go ahead, you can use the following library.

[https://github.com/greiman/SdFat](http://SdFAT%20Library)

This library supports Long File names and if I remember correctly, the Arduino Standard Library is also the wrapper of the library created by the same author.

[https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=58549.msg421288#msg421288](http://Arduino%20Forum%20Link)

***Note: Long File Names consumes much RAM.***

Comment: Thank you very much! It works fine now. I'm aware of the RAM usage. If it will be a problem later on I know where to search. :) I didn't realized the deference between the two libs first.